# version increment using OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT

Tags: version

When I'm trying to auto increment using  OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT, for the first 2 record i'm getting the version same i.e 1, and from the 3rd record it is working fine i.e from the 3rd record i'm getting version as 2,3,4 etc.what might be the reason for getting same version number for the 2nd record ? below is the reference code

from the 2nd record onwards the version creation should work properly, i.e for 2nd record the version number should be 2